# Mongo Java - list all documents which has data as phone number or credit card number or zip code when field name is not known to us

Tags: java, mongodb

Could you please suggest a option in **Mongo Java** to find all documents which has data as phone number or credit card number or zip code, when field name is not known to us.

I tried this but this is not working at all.

```
AggregateIterable<Document> output = collection.aggregate(
    Arrays.asList(
        new Document(
            "$project", new Document(
                "x", new Document(
                    "$objectToArray", "$$CURRENT"
                )
            )
        ),
        new Document("$unwind", "$x"),
        new Document(
            "$match", new Document(
                "x.k", new Document(
                    "$in", new BasicDBObject("$regex", "^(ISBN(-10)?:? )?([-0-9xX ]{13}|[0-9X]{10})$")
                )
            )
        )
    )
);
```

Comment: Can you post some sample data, please?

Answer (score 0):

```
For example Input
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("5a0bf2604510c319181df436"), 
    "name" : "Oneindb2", 
    "number" : 11, 
    "phonenumber" : 111111
}
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("5a0bf2604510c319181df437"), 
    "dname" : "creditCardtwoindb2",   
    "zipc" : "5670228"
}
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("5a0bf2604510c319181df439"), 
    "name" : "creditCardfourindb2", 
    "CHECKnumber" : 56, 
    "checkISO" : "second_iso"
}
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("5a0bf2604510c319181df43a"), 
    "name" : "creditCardfiveindb2", 
    "ddnumber" : 56, 
    "ISOS" : "second_iso"
}
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("5a0bf2604510c319181df438"), 
    "cname" : " 57656yuio89789"
    "personnumber" : 33, 
    "NISO" : "three_iso"
}


*Expected output is*

{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("5a0bf2604510c319181df436"), 
    "name" : "Oneindb2", 
    "number" : 11, 
    "pnumber" : 111111
}
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("5a0bf2604510c319181df437"), 
    "dname" : "creditCardtwoindb2",   
    "zipc" : "5670228"
}
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("5a0bf2604510c319181df438"), 
    "cname" : " 57656yuio89789"
    "number" : NumberInt(33), 
    "ISO11" : "three_iso"
}
because these documents fields (at least one field) has either phone number or credit card number or zip code
Note: field names are not same in all the documents it may vary.
```